# expressjs repo documentation

Tags: node.js, express

I want to understand the internal working of Expressjs (just curious). Much of the thing are clear but I am not able to understand the chaining of routing and middleware. How expressjs add all the route and middleware to path `/` and how it keep the stack of route with middleware internally

So I will be very thankful to you if you provide some documentation or link from where I get the understanding how expressjs work internally

Thanks

Comment: It's one week and no response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpressJS is just an HTTP server allowing you to route and manipulate the received requests and returning a response.

So if you carefully look at the HTTP packet format below,

[image: HTTP Packet]

you can find the method and the path in the first line.

So, basically here express-router has a regex matcher that tries to match the HTTP request it receives to the predefined routes declared in the express application.

If you check [L:43 Router](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/547fdd41dca9ae9c49956748cc0bd1f011310fb6/lib/router/route.js#L43), here it shows that the route you declare is just a function containing 3 constants:

1. path - That would be a path to match.
2. stack - Following a proper format, the URL is broken down using the `/` separator and a stack is formed in order of it's parsing, comprising another function called layer.
3. methods - Methods are the HTTP methods that we declare along with the path.

### Parsing

So when a request is made, let's suppose: `http://localhost:8000/user/1/test`

1. We get the path: `/user/1/test`
2. The router's [handle function](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/547fdd41dca9ae9c49956748cc0bd1f011310fb6/lib/router/index.js#L136) is executed. Then this path is broken down into layers and formed a stack: ['user', '*', 'test']
3. This stack is then matched with that of the route objects that are pre-declared in the application and are used as [`Route`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js) functional objects.
4. As soon as it finds the match the callback is executed!